# Python Unit Testing: Assert Statements

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to write unit tests for a function that returns a list of lists. What is the best way to check that this output is as expected? The actual string value that is returned is not important at all, I just need to validate the format is the same [['any string],[any string]]

I am having trouble finding the correct assert statement to use. I am generating fake string data using faker.  Here is an example of what I am trying as of now

```
import unittest
import faker
class TestListElements(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pdf_text = [faker.pystr()]
        v1 = Pdf_class("pdf file path") 
        self.expected = pdf_text
        self.result = v1.get_pdf_data 

    def test_type(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.result, list)
        self.assertIsInstance(self.expected, list)
```

Comment: Use `all` and check that all sub lists are lists (of strings) e.g. `l = [["Hello"], ["World"]]; all(isinstance(x, list) for x in l)`?

Comment: @NelsonGon can you clarify what you mean by 'all' ? would this be assertAll ?

Comment: The builtin function [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: Is `v1.get_pdf_data` the actual list, or a method that, when called, *returns* a list?

Comment: v1.get_pdf_data is calling the method that returns a list

Comment: Then you need to actually call it: `self.result = v1.get_pdf_data()`.